# Is it possible to run a batch script remotely on a Windows machine from Linux without installing ssh?

Tags: linux, windows, remote-access

I am looking for a way in Linux to run a batch script on a remote Windows machine. I already searched some forums and the Internet and found e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095807/run-a-windows-xp-bat-script-remotely-from-a-ubuntu-machine).

It seems that the easiest way so far is using `ssh`. But do Linux or Windows also offer some built-in tools to solve this problem (something like at-command for Linux-to-Windows)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [winexe](http://eol.ovh.org/winexe/) it's basically psExec that you can run from a *nix box.

Comment: Wow, I have a hacky screen-scraping RDP client that installs SSH that I'm never using again.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [DoIt](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/doit/) or the [openssh windows port](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

From a Windows machine you can use BeyondExec to execute anything on a Windows machine with a proper user name and password. So if you set up a VM with Windows and BeyondExec on the Linux machine, you should be able to do what you want.

Note that some virus scanners don't like BeyondExec. Which is hardly a surprise. :)

Answer (score 0):

doit is great, 10x Pi